# Counting and printing a serial number +1 if less than last serial number JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, addition, counter

So I have two serial numbers and 199 serials in between them:

899720101000105500 (first)

899720101000105699 (last)

I need to print the first serial and then all 199 up to the last serial. The only thing I've found is just +1 to the first serial every time the loop runs and printing it.

I've copied/pasted different parts and this is what I have:

```
var lowEnd = 899720101000105500;
var highEnd = 899720101000105699;
var arr = [];
while(lowEnd <= highEnd){
   arr.push(lowEnd++);
}
```

Is there a max number length you can store in a variable?

Comment: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which should be `9007199254740991` or `2^53 - 1`.

Comment: See [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/1737627) for more details.

Comment: You can test that `lowEnd === lowEnd + 1` which is `true`, so it's not safe for you to do that, convert them to `string`, or split them to many smaller `number`s, then do the calculation.

Comment: Ah I see. That's smaller than my number. How would you recommend I cut it up? that last 4 numbers (5500 and 5699) are to only unique digits in the number so maybe make the first numbers a string, count 5500 to 5699 and then append to the string of the first digits?

Comment: Yes, if you already know only the last 4 digits will change, that's should be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for this specific problem for anyone that may come across this. Make the static parts of the number (the digits that don't change) a string and just use the digits that do change (for me it was the last 4) to count and then add the string to the count and log it.

```
var serialNumber = 5500;

while(serialNumber <= 5699)
{
    serialNumber = serialNumber + 1;
    var fullNumber = "89972010100010" + serialNumber;
    console.log(fullNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (let i = BigInt(899720101000105500); i <= 899720101000105699; BigInt(i++)) {        
         console.log(i + '')        
 }
```

Comment: You should avoid code-only answers. Answers that provide a rationale are much more likely to be helpful